# Saving pyqgis QgsGeometryAnalyzer.dissolve output in memory?

Tags: pyqgis, in-memory

How to save pyqgis [QgsGeometryAnalyzer.dissolve](https://qgis.org/api/1.6/classQgsGeometryAnalyzer.html#53d54803e5ce52c5147a8fc9640b8fc5) output in memory (temporal layer)?

Usage example:

```
from qgis.analysis import *
shp_path = "C:\shape_file.shp"
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().dissolve(layer, shp_path, onlySelectedFeatures=False, uniqueIdField=-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These algorithms are old and unmaintained. They can produce only shapefiles. They have been dropped in QGIS 3 in favor of the Processing framework, in which you can select the output format.

So you should better not use this class in QGIS 2 and move now to Processing, it will be easier when you will move to QGIS 3.

```
import processing
processing.alglist('dissolve')
Dissolve--------------------------------------------->qgis:dissolve
v.dissolve - Dissolves boundaries between adjacent areas sharing a common category number or attribute.--->grass7:v.dissolve
```

How to use Processing from Python
https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

Comment: Ok, I will use processing instead of qgis.analysis.